# I have created an invoice in open erp through a web service , but i can't register its payment and change its status into "paid"

Tags: python, web-services, odoo

Code that i use to create invoice , it successfully creates the invoice , but i can't change its status to paid . Maybe im missing something

account_invoice_dict = {
                     'date_invoice': today,
                     'partner_id' : student_id,
                     'account_id' : account_id,
                     'voucher_no' : voucher_no
                                }

account_invoice_id = oerp.create('account.invoice', account_invoice_dict)